# Extracting social networking structure in R

Tags: r, recursion, social-networking

I'm trying prepare a particular dataset for network analysis, but first, I need to extract the relationship between nodes from that data. The data appears in the following format:

```
id  | structure_var
1   | 1
2   | 1.1
3   | 1.2
4   | 1.2.1
5   | 1.2.2
6   | 1.3
7   | 2
8   | 2.1
9   | 2.1.1
```

The desired output is this (both from and to correspond to the ID values above):

```
 from  | to
    1  | 2
    1  | 3
    1  | 6
    3  | 4
    3  | 5
    7  | 8
    8  | 9
```

The best I could come up with so far is this:

```
library(stringr)
extract_structure = function(x,y=seq_along(x),connections=character()){

  depth  = str_count(x,"\\.")
  parent = gsub("(\\d+)\\..*","\\1",x)
  parent_iterator = as.numeric(unique(parent))


  for(i in parent_iterator){
    a = y[which(x==as.character(i))]
    b = y[which(depth==1 & parent==i)]
    if(length(a)>0 & length(b)>0){connections = c(connections,paste(a,b,sep="-"))}
  }

  zero_depth = which(depth<1)
  next_y = y[-zero_depth]
  next_x = gsub("^\\d+\\.","",x[-zero_depth])

  if(sum(depth)>0){extract_structure(x=next_x,y=next_y,connections=connections)} 
    else{return(connections)}
}


extract_structure(x=comment_structure)
"1-2" "1-3" "1-6" "7-8" "2-9" "8-9" "3-4" "3-5"
```

But as you can see, the answer does not retain history, which is why it connects 2 and 9 when it shouldn't. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to best program it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done super easily with string processing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

merge(data %>% rename(from_ID = id, 
                      from_structure = structure_var),
      data %>% rename(to_ID = id, 
                      to_structure = structure_var) ) %>%
  filter(paste0("^", from_structure , "\\.[0-9]$") %>%
           stri_detect_regex(to_structure, .) )
```

Comment: Champion! thank you -- it worked beautifully and the solution turned out to be much simpler than I expected.

Comment: The only downside of this solution is that it requires a cross-join and therefore isn't really scalable, but that will do for me. Many thanks!